# Loop through the lines of two files in parallel

Tags: bash, shell-script, control-flow

The object of the script I'm making is to compare two series of files. The file names are themselves stored into two separate files, one path per line. My idea is to have two `while read` loops, one for each list of file names, but how can I mix the two loops together?

```
while read compareFile <&3; do     
 if [[ ! $server =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
    continue
 fi   
    echo "Comparing file - $compareFile"
 if diff "$compareFile" _(other file from loop?_) >/dev/null ; then
     echo Same
 else
      echo Different
 fi 
done 3</infanass/dev/admin/filestoCompare.txt
```

I need to be able to compare files from two different lists at the same time through two while read loops... Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you intenting to make this script as a king of challenge? If not so, powerful tools already exist to compare files, like `diff`.

Comment: "*kind* of challenge", sorry

Comment: @lgeorget the OP is using `diff`.

Comment: ah, *files* from two lists. Sorry for the useless comments...

Comment: Please avoid [cross-posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579578/2-while-read-loops)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need two loops; you just need to read from two files in the one loop.

```
while read compareFile1 <&3 && read compareFile2 <&4; do     
 if [[ ! $server =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
    continue
 fi   
    echo "Comparing file - $compareFile"
 if diff "$compareFile1" "$compareFile2" >/dev/null ; then
     echo Same
 else
      echo Different
 fi 
done 3</infanass/dev/admin/filestoCompare.txt 4<other_file
```

Comment: thats alot more less code thanks! how to i handle an empty line exception at the same time then for the two loops?

Comment: @mkrouse, I don't know what you were doing with that $server variable there before, but however you test for an empty line on the one variable, you just do the same on the other...

Answer (score 9):

### Method 1: use what you know

Since you already know how to loop over one file, you could combine the files and then process the combined files. The command [`paste`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) joins two files line by line. It puts a tab between the lines coming from the two files, so this solution assumes that there are no tabs in your file names. (You can change the separator but you have to find a character that isn't present in a file name.)

```
paste -- "$list1.txt" "list2.txt" |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r file1 file2 rest; do
  diff -q -- "$file1" "$file2"
  case $? in
    0) status='same';;
    1) status='different';;
    *) status='ERROR';;
  esac
  echo "$status $file1 $file2"
done
```

If you want to skip blank lines, you need to do it in each file separately, since `paste` might match a blank line from one file with a non-blank line from another file. You can use `grep` to filter the non-blank lines.

```
paste -- <(grep '[^[:space:]]' "$list1.txt") <(grep '[^[:space:]]' "list2.txt") |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r file1 file2 rest; do
  …
```

Note that if the two files have different lengths, you'll get an empty `$file2` (regardless of which list ended first).

### Method 2: loop over two files

You can put as complex a command as you like in the condition of the while loop. If you put `read file1 <&3 && read file2 <&4` then the loop will run as long as both files have a line to read, i.e. until one file runs out.

```
while read -u 3 -r file1 && read -u 4 -r file2; do
  …
done 3<list1..txt 4<list2.txt
```

If you want to skip over blank lines, it's a little more complicated, because you have to do the skipping in the two files independently. The easy way is to break the problem into two parts: skip the blank lines from one file, and process the non-blank lines. One method to skip the blank lines is to process through `grep` as above. Watch out for the necessary space between the `<` redirection operator and the `<(` that starts a command susbtitution.

```
while read -u 3 -r file1 && read -u 4 -r file2; do
  …
done 3< <(grep '[^[:space:]]' "$list1.txt") 4< <(grep '[^[:space:]]' "list2.txt")
```

Another method is to write a function that behaves like `read` but skips blank lines. This function can work by calling `read` in a loop. It doesn't have to be a function, but a function is the best approach, both to organize your code and because that piece of code needs to be called twice. In the function, `${!#}` is an instance of the bash construct `${!VARIABLE}` which evaluates to the value of the variable whose name is the value of `VARIABLE`; here the variable is the special variable `#` which contains the number of positional parameter, so `${!#}` is the last positional parameter.

```
function read_nonblank {
  while read "$@" &&
        [[ ${!#} !~ [^[:space:]] ]]
  do :; done
}
while read_nonblank -u 3 -r file1 && read_nonblank -u 4 -r file2; do
  …
done 3<list1..txt 4<list2.txt
```

Comment: I like the use of read's `-u` option

Comment: I have a question about the 2nd method. How to use variables instead of files? I tried to use something like `done 3< <(echo $var_name1) 4< <(echo $var_name2)` , but it returns `Syntax error: redirection unexpected` .

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov You're trying to use a process substitution `<(…)`, which a ksh/bash/zsh feature, in dash. You can use here documents instead: `… done 3<<EOF 4<<EOF|$var_name1|EOF|$var_name2|EOF|`, replace `|` by line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use `read -ra` instead of just `read`. Assuming the `filestoCompare.txt` contained 2 columns with the file names in each, the `read -ra` would read both columns in at the same time and assign them into an array, `compareFile`. This array could then be accessed so that index 0 would be the first file and index 1 would be the 2nd file each time through the `while` loop.

#### Example

Say I have this file: `filestoCompare.txt`, and it contains the following:

```
file1 file2
file3 file4
file5 file6
```

The command to go through this file would be as follows:

```
$ while read -ra a ; do printf "%s\t%s\n" ${a[0]} ${a[1]}; done < filestoCompare.txt
file1   file2
file3   file4
file5   file6
```

If the 2 files are indeed separate files such as:

```
#list1
file1
file2
file3

#list2
file4
file5
file6
```

They can be joined together with the `paste` command like so:

```
$ paste list1 list2 > list1and2
```

Here's the contents of list1and2:

```
$ cat list1and2
file1   file4
file2   file5
file3   file6
```

Comment: But that's not the input format: the lists are in two different files. You could `join` them first.

Comment: @Gilles  - I know that's not the input format, I believe I even said that "...Assuming the filestoCompare.txt contained 2 columns with the file names in each...". I understand your contention and don't disagree. The OP hasn't provided any further guidance on this question since posting it.

Comment: @Gilles - what if I add an example showing how to use the command `paste` to join the 2 files? Would that get you to undownvote?